# Git stash to patch with untracked files

Tags: git

How can I make Git stash with untracked files, push it to patch and restore it in another computer.

```
git stash save -u feature
git stash show -p > patch
git apply patch
```

But path hasn't untracked files

Comment: Can you try using `git stash show -p stash@{0} > patch` to create the patch file.

Comment: @donut: won't help; `git stash show` just diffs the work-tree commit against its parent.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A normal `git stash` creates a [stash bag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20412685/1256452) that consists of two commits: the index, and the work-tree.

Using `-u` or `-a` (or their other spellings) creates a [three-commit stash bag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589663/1256452).  The third commit contains (only) the untracked (`-u`) or untracked-and-ignored / "all" (`-a`) files, i.e., it omits all tracked files.

If you need this in the form of a patch, the trick is to create two patches:

- changes to tracked files: `git stash show -p` (what you have so far), plus
- the entire contents of the third commit, as a patch.

The easiest way to get the second bullet item is to `git diff` that third commit against an empty tree.  Git [always has an empty tree in every repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9766506/1256452) whose ID is the magic number `4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904`.  So a diff between that tree, and `stash^3`, will consist of a series of git patches that add the untracked files:

```
git diff 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 stash^3
```

You can then simply combine the two patches into one:

```
git stash show -p > patch
git diff 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 stash^3 >> patch
```

(See the last link above for a way to avoid hard-coding the magic number for the empty tree.  Also, if you just want to *view* the `u` commit, use `git show`: `git show stash^3`, for instance.)

Comment: I do    
  `git stash save --all`
but when I do  
`git diff stash^3`
zsh: no matches found: stash^3  

If I understand right I need to make these three steps ?
`git stash save --all`
`git stash show -p > patch`
`git diff 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 stash^3 >> patch`

Comment: zsh is attempting to handle the `^3` itself, instead of passing it on to git.  You must protect the `^` from zsh, with backslash or quotes, e.g., `'stash^3'` instead of just `stash^3`.  (Different shells have different Special Characters, sh and bash don't need this.)

Comment: Thanks just moved to zsh ) So after `git diff 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 stash^3 >> patch` I get patch but also contains .gitignored files ?

Comment: Yes, because you used `--all` rather than `--untracked`.  You can restore and drop that stash and make one with just `-u` if that's what you want instead.

Comment: If you have trouble remembering the sha, just write it down on an index card and mumble it to yourself as you fall asleep each night.

Comment: @xdhmoore: heh. Or, click on the link and see ways to compute it (my favorite is `git hash-object -t tree /dev/null`).

Comment: I am still not seeing untracked files in the stash

Comment: @shigazaru: see my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52357450/1256452).

Comment: To get only files / paths from a particular directory tree and pipe directly into `git apply`: 
`git diff 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 stash^3 [<path spec>] | git apply -`

Comment: A little script: patchName="patch-`date +'%Y-%m-%d'_%H:%M:%S`";  
git stash show -p >${patchName}; 
git diff 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 stash^3 >>${patchName}; 
echo "${patchName}"