# Commit to master lost my commit

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

So silly me, I had lost control of my repository a little bit,

I had a commit of 14,000 changes pending

I was using the mac github desktop application. I simply gave the commit a title, description and hit commit to master. Some loading went on, then all of a sudden the whole commit disappeared.

That is literally all I did and I have now lost a weeks worth of work.

Any chance I can retrieve this lost commit?

Git Reflog gives

```
86d0999 HEAD@{0}: cherry-pick: On master: GitHub: Stashing to pull in remote changes
04f207b HEAD@{1}: merge 04f207b: Fast-forward
ce9f5bf HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD^
04f207b HEAD@{3}: commit: Table Functionality
ce9f5bf
```

What is the erroneous line at the bottom?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instead of Committing Files, I hit 'Sync' in GitHub app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052451/instead-of-committing-files-i-hit-sync-in-github-app)

Comment: Can you look for any dangling commits? `git fsck --lost-found`

Comment: @JoshLee Thanks for the link! Thankfully this worked a treat!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you didnt actually do a commit it may be hard. Check the reflogs.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

Comment: I did the commit? But during its loading it disappeared?

Comment: Git reflog gives me a few things, ive added it above @Thomas