# how to view untracked files that were "git stash -u"

Tags: git, git-stash

Stashing content in git is very useful.
when stashing untrack files and going through your stash like this

```
echo test > foo
git stash -u # foo is stashed
git stash show -p stash@{0}
```

untracked files are not shown.
how can we see them?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git stash to patch with untracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818155/git-stash-to-patch-with-untracked-files)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to look at the third stash commit.  But "just need to" understates things a little bit, and this makes no sense until you know what the three stash commits *are*.  To see what I mean, read on.

#### Setup: what to know about stashes

When you run `git stash save` or `git stash push`, Git's normal action is to create *two* commits, neither of which are on any branch.  If you draw the "before" picture like this, you would have this series of commits:

```
...--o--o--*   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

After `git stash save` completes, you have two *new* commits that are not on branch `branch` and not on any other branch either:

```
...--o--o--*   <-- branch (HEAD)
           |\
           i-w   <-- the stash
```

The `w` commit saves the work-tree state while the `i` commit saves the index.  Each of these two commits is very much like any other commit, and in fact, the `i` commit is made using most of the normal `git commit` mechanism: Git writes the current index to an internal *tree* object using `git write-tree`, then makes a *commit* object using `git commit-tree`.  If you don't know what these internal objects are, don't worry too much about that: the point is that this is also how `git commit` does most of its job, by writing a tree and then a commit object.  (The rest of `git commit` consists of collecting your log message first, and updating the branch name at the end.)

The `w` commit is a little more complicated because it has the *form* (but not intent) of a *merge* commit, with two parents instead of one.  But basically it saves a snapshot of the work-tree, as if you had run `git add` on all your tracked files.

When you add `--all` or `--include-untracked` (`-a` or `-u` for short), what `git stash` does is that it adds a *third* commit, which we can draw this way:

```
...--o--o--*   <-- branch (HEAD)
           |\
           i-w   <-- the stash
            /
           u
```

The third commit is a snapshot, but it is a very odd snapshot.  It contains *only* the untracked files—either the untracked-but-not-ignored files (`git stash save -u`), or the untracked files *including* the untracked-and-ignored files (`git stash save -a`).  It also has no *parent* commit.

**So we have 3 commits in total for:**
**`i`** - *index*
**`w`** - *working-tree*
**`u`** - *untracked*

#### The stash "stack", commit hash IDs, and parents

One reason<sup>1</sup> that Git added the `push` verb, as in `git stash push`—which is otherwise basically a synonym for `save`—is that when you make a new stash, Git uses the stash *reflog* to keep track of earlier stashes.  The current stash is `stash@{0}` in reflog terms, and the earlier stash becomes `stash@{1}`.

Each of these names is just a specific case of a more general thing that Git gives you: you can refer to any commit by *any name that resolves to the correct hash ID*.  The "true name" of any commit is its big ugly hash ID.  [The gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) has the complete description of all the ways you can spell a hash ID to Git; using a name like `branch` or `stash` is one such way.

Using the name `stash` locates commit `w` specifically.  Git then uses `w` itself to find commit `i`, and, if it exists, commit `u`.  Git can do this because each commit includes the hash IDs of its *parent* commits.  What makes `w` have the form of a merge commit is that it has at least two parents: `i`, the index commit, and `*`, the commit you were sitting on when you ran `git stash save` or `git stash push` in the first place.

We can modify most revision specifiers (like `stash`) by adding a caret `^` character and a number to look specifically at the numbered parent.  Writing `stash^1` is a way of naming commit `*`; writing `stash^2` is a way of naming commit `i`.  If commit `u` exists, writing `stash^3` names it.  Note that on some systems (Windows), `^` may be a special character that requires doubling or quoting, so instead of `stash^3` you might need `stash^^3`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The other reason was to add the ability to do partial stashing using pathspecs: `git stash save` took any extra arguments as a message to include in the stash commits, so they needed a new verb that used `-m` to specify the message, leaving room for pathspec arguments.

---

#### Viewing the `u` commit

We can view *any* commit using `git show`.  For stash `w` commits this misfires because Git thinks that the `w` commit is a merge, so we can use `git stash show` instead.  (It *is* a merge, just not one that `git show` can show properly.)  My [earlier answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22819771/1256452) calls for using `git diff` on the `u` commit, because in that particular case, we don't want to get the header that `git show` shows, but if we just want to look at the untracked file commit, it's OK to use `git show` here:

```
git show stash^3
```

for instance.  Here is the output for the `foo` example above:

```
$ git show stash^3
commit 4c9bd2486706980f5a492d19c49270381db2d796
Author: Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Sep 16 12:35:03 2018 -0700

    untracked files on master: f72737e initial

diff --git a/foo b/foo
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..257cc56
--- /dev/null
+++ b/foo
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+foo
```

Using a name like `stash@{1}` identifies the commit in reflog entry #1, which is the next stash in your "stash stack".  (The reflog starts counting from zero, so `stash` and `stash@{0}` mean the same commit.)  So for `stash@{1}` you would need `stash@{1}^3` or perhaps `stash@{1}^^3`.