# Lost tracked files when doing git stash --include-untracked

Tags: git, git-stash, git-untracked

when I did `git status`, there are both tracked and untracked files. Early the day, I just learned that `git stash --include-untracked` would stash the untracked files. It worked for me at that time. So I thought `git stash --include-untracked` would save both tracked and untracked files' change. But when I `git stash apply`, there is only untracked files' change left. The tracked files' change are lost.

Comment: Was it the exact command you used? Or did you add other flags? (like `keep-index`, maybe?)

Comment: @Nah. I just found out it was because I didn't apply the most recent stash. If I applied the most recent one, it keeps both tracked and untracked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### There's something suspicious here, but it's probably not the stash itself

`git stash --include-untracked`, which can be spelled `git stash -u` for short, makes *three* commits for the stash.

The first two are the same two as usual: one to hold whatever was in the index at the time you ran `git stash`, and the other to hold whatever was in the work-tree—but tracked files only—at that time.  In other words, the `i` commit holding the index holds the result of `git write-tree`, and the `w` commit holds the result of (the equivalent of) `git add -u && git write-tree` (although the stash code does this the hard way, or did in the old days of shell script stash).

That's all that the stash would have if you ran `git stash` *without* `--all` or `--include-untracked`: it would have the two commits for `i` (index state) and `w` (work-tree state), both of which have the current commit `C` as their first parent.  Commit `w` has `i` as its second parent:

```
...--o--o--C   <-- HEAD
           |\
           i-w   <-- stash
```

If you *do* add `-u` or `-a`, however, you get a *three*-commit stash: commit `w` acquires a third parent, a commit we can call `u`, that holds the untracked files.  This third parent has no parent of its own (is an orphan / root-commit), so the drawing is now:

```
...--o--o--C   <-- HEAD
           |\
           i-w   <-- stash
            /
           u
```

The interesting thing about this new commit, and its effect in the work-tree as well, is this:  *Commit `u` contains **only** untracked files.**

Remember that a commit is a full and complete snapshot of all (tracked) files.  Commit `u` is made by—in a temporary index—*discarding* all *tracked* files and instead, tracking some or all *untracked* files.  This step either adds only the untracked-but-not-ignored files (`git stash -u`), or *all* files (`git stash -a`).  Then Git writes commit `u`, using `git write-tree` to turn the temporary index into a tree to put into commit `u`, so that commit `u` contains *only* the selected files.

Now that these selected files are in commit `u`, `git stash` **removes them from the work-tree**.  In practice, it used to just run `git clean` with appropriate options.  The new fancier C-coded `git stash` still does the equivalent (but, one might hope, with fewer bugs; see below).

This is similar to what it does for the files in `i` and/or `w`: it effectively does a `git reset --hard`, so that the work-tree's tracked files match the `HEAD` commit.  (That is, it does this unless you use `--keep-index`, in which case it resets the files to match the `i` commit.)  The `git reset` at this point has no effect on *untracked* files, which are outside the scope of `git reset`, and no effect on the current branch since the reset deliberately keeps that at the `HEAD`.

Having stashed some untracked files in commit `u`, though, `git stash` then *removes* those files from the work-tree.  That's quite important later (and maybe also immediately).

**Note:** there was a bug in combining `git stash push` with pathspecs, that potentially affects everything, but especially affects the stash variants made with `-u` or `-a`, where some versions of Git remove *too many* files.  That is, you might `git stash` just some subset of your files, but then Git would `git reset --hard` or `git clean` *all* files, or too many files.  (I believe these are all fixed today, but in general, I don't recommend using `git stash` at all, and especially not the fancy pathspec variants.  Removing untracked files that weren't actually stashed is particularly egregious behavior, and *some* versions of Git do that!)

#### You describe an `apply`-time problem, but maybe not the usual one

Here's what you said:

> I thought `git stash --include-untracked` would save both tracked and untracked files' change.

As always, Git doesn't save *changes*, it saves *snapshots*.

> But when I 'git stash apply`, there is only untracked files' change left. The tracked files' change are lost.

Applying a normal (no-untracked-files) stash is done in one of two ways, depending on whether you use the `--index` flag.  The variant without `--index` is easier to explain, since it literally just *ignores* the `i` commit.  (The variant with the `--index` flag first uses `git apply --index` on a diff, and if that fails, suggests that you try without `--index`.  If you *want* the effect of `--index`, this is terrible advice and you should ignore it.  For this answer, though, let's ignore the `--index` option entirely.)

**Note:** this is not the `--keep-index` flag, but rather the `--index` flag.  The `--keep-index` flag applies only when *creating* a stash.  The `--index` flag applies when *applying* a stash.

To apply the `w` commit, Git runs `git merge-recursive` directly.  This is not something you should ever do as a user, and when `git stash` does it, that's not really all that wise either, but that's what it does.  The effect is a lot like running `git merge`, except that if you have uncommitted changes in your index and/or work-tree, it may become impossible to return to this state in any sort of automated way.

If you start with a "clean" index and work-tree, though—that is, if `git status` says `nothing to commit, working tree clean`—this merge operation is almost exactly the same as a regular `git merge` or `git cherry-pick`, in many ways.  (Note that both `git merge` and `git cherry-pick` *require* that things be clean, at least by default.)  The merge operation runs with the *merge base* set to the parent of commit `w`, the *current* or `--ours` commit being the current commit as usual, and the other or `--theirs` commit being commit `w`.

That is, suppose that your commit graph now looks like this:

```
       o--o--A--B   <-- branch (HEAD)
      /
...--o--o--C
           |\
           i-w   <-- stash
            /
           u
```

so that you are on commit `B`.  The merge operation to apply the stash does a three-way merge with `C` as the merge base and `w` as the `--theirs` commit, and the current commit/work-tree as the `--ours` commit.  Git diffs `C` vs `B` to see what *we* changed, and `C` vs `w` to see what *they* changed, and combines the two sets of differences.

This is how the merge into `B` will run, *provided* that Git can first un-stash commit `u`.  The usual problem at this point is that Git *can't* un-stash `u`.

Remember that commit `u` contains exactly (and only) the *untracked* files that were present when you made the stash, and that Git then removed with `git clean` (and appropriate options).  **These files must still be absent from the work-tree.**  If they are *not* absent, `git stash apply` will be unable to extract the files from `u` and will not proceed.

#### Since the untracked files are untracked, it's hard to know if they changed

> But when I 'git stash apply`, there is only untracked files' change left. The tracked files' change are lost.

You talk about *changes* in untracked files.

Git of course doesn't store changes, so you can't find them that way.  And if the files are untracked, they're not in the index right now either.  So: how do you know they're *changed?*  You need some other set of files to which to compare them.

The step that extracts commit `u` is supposed to be all-or-nothing: it should either extract all `u` files, or not.  If it does extract all `u` files, `git stash apply` should go on to attempt to merge, somewhat as if by `git cherry-pick -n` (except that cherry-pick writes to the index too), commit `w` in the stash.  That should leave you with extracted `u` files *and* merged `w`-vs-`C` changes, in your work-tree.

If there are conflicts between `C`-vs-work-tree vs `C`-vs-`w`, you should have the conflict markers present in the work-tree, and your index should have been expanded as usual for a conflicted merge.

If you can make a reproducer for your problem, that would probably provide huge amounts of clarity here.

Comment: Thanks for all the conception correction. Those are way more important than a simple command outcome. I reproduced the steps I made in a demo, the `git stash -u` and then `git stash apply` did exactly what I expected. So I check the history of my command, it turns out I applied stash@{1}` instead of `stash@{0}` and `stash@{1}` one happen to be the experiment I did earlier which targets untracked files only.

Comment: I would love a TL;DR of this answer that just shows how to recover the untracked files that seem to have got lost

Answer (score 4):

I found this question because I found myself in the same situation - I had copy and pasted `git stash -u` from another SO answer as a way to supposedly stash my untracked files, then was horrified when I did `git stash apply` and they weren't restored.

@torek has two [excellent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58565922/202168) and [very detailed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52357762/202168) answers which explain what git is doing when you `git stash -u` and why the files are not restored. With their help I think I have pieced together the operations needed to restore them.

This will rely on you not having stashed again or done other git stuff in the meantime, if you have then some of below may need adjusting.

If you read any of @torek's answers you will know that `git stash -u` actually made three commits - one of them has your untracked files in it, but it's not the one that gets applied by `git stash apply` and won't be shown in `git stash list`.

You should be able to find it by:

```
git show stash^3
```

If that looks like your untracked files, you're in luck!

Now just:

```
git cherry-pick --no-commit $(git rev-parse stash^3)
```

This will restore the untracked files... albeit staged as "Changes to be committed"

(`git reset` to un-stage them)

Comment: I think you've come up with a pretty good summary of how to get those files. You could use `git read-tree` but `git cherry-pick` is probably safer. One way to shorten this slightly: instead of `git show -s --pretty=format:"%H" stash^3` just run `git rev-parse stash^3`.

Comment: @torek thanks I've updated with that rev-parse tip