# git stash apply conflict after rebasing and amending a commit

Tags: git, git-stash, git-merge-conflict

I stashed my changes to rebase and amend a commit.

After rebasing, I deleted a file, staged it and the ran `commit --amend`

Unfortunately the file in question had been modified when I stashed the work.

Now after `rebase --continue` I can't `stash apply` because it has conflicts.

```
deleted in updated upstream and modified in stashed changes
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: There's probably an easier way, but you could try [exporting your stash as a patch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160638/how-can-i-format-patch-with-what-i-stash-away) and then applying the patch.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the conflict just as you would a merge conflict:

Following a merge of `branch_two` into `branch_one`, a file that was deleted in `branch_one` and modified in `branch_two` will be placed into the working tree, and shown in `git status` with the label `deleted by us`.

You can `git add` (or `git rm`) the file to mark resolution either way.

If you decide to `git add`, you can remove the file from your index while keeping it in your working tree with `git reset HEAD <file>`, just as you would ordinarily.